# Installing a theme for OpenCart: Notice: unserialize () Error at offset

Tags: serialization, themes, opencart

I need some help. Finally, after a lot of problems I installed a theme for Opencart. But the problem is that the theme seems to be installed normally, but I get this error at the top of my frontend:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1150 bytes in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myshop/index.php on line 54
```

And this one at the top of my backend:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1150 bytes in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myshop/admin/index.php on line 37
```

How can I fix this issue?